# Removing empty parentheses around month in biblatex windycity style reflist environment

Tags: biblatex, windycity

For my thesis, I need to add references in footnotes and a bibliography that is sorted by date. To achieve this, I switched from biblatex-chicago to the windycity style in biblatex. This works fine for the notes themselves, but I get some empty parentheses in my bibliography. I found out that this is caused by the fact that some of my references have dates with months and days, but I set `date=year` in my preamble. The empty parentheses would normally enclose the month. How can I remove all the months and days from dates without having to alter my .bib file.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[reflist=true, style=windycity, date=year]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\begin{document}
    Date with month: \cite{shore}
    
    Date without month: \cite{doody}
    
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

moewe's answer manages to get rid of the parenthesis but it still retains the difference in style of those items that have a month and those that done. I figured the easy solution might be to just remove the month and day from every bib item using

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \clearfield{doi}%
    \clearfield{month}%
    \clearfield{day}}
```

This seems to work in providing the output I want. Is there any reason why I would use this?

Answer (score 1):

`windycity` basically operates under the assumption that you never explicitly set the date format to `year`. Here is an attempt to make `windycity` aware of the date format. We replace all tests for `month` (`\iffieldundef{month}`) in `issue+month+etc` by the test `\ifdatehasyearonlyprecision{}`, which also takes into account the `date` output format.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[reflist=true, style=windycity, date=year]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+month+etc}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{year}
    {\ifdatehasyearonlyprecision{}
       {}
       {\setunit{\space}%
        \printtext[parens]{\printdate}}}
    {\ifboolexpr{ test {\iffieldundef{volume}}
                  and test {\iffieldundef{number}}}
       {\iffieldundef{journal}
          {}
          {\setunit{\addcomma\space}}%
        \ifdatehasyearonlyprecision{}
          {\usebibmacro{issue+season+year}}%
          {\usebibmacro{reflist+year+day}%
           \printdate}}%
       {\ifdatehasyearonlyprecision{}
          {\setunit{\space}%
           \usebibmacro{reflist+issue+season}}%
          {\ifstrequal{#1}{noparens}
             {\usebibmacro{reflist+year+day}%
              \newunit
              \printdate}%
             {\usebibmacro{reflist+year+day}%
              \setunit{\space}%
              \printtext[parens]{\printdate}}}}}}

\begin{document}
  Date with month: \cite{shore}

  Date without month: \cite{doody}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Shore, Bradd. 1991. “Twice-Born, Once Conceived: Meaning Construction and Cultural Cognition.” American Anthropologist, new series, 93, no. 1: 9–27.]

I wouldn't call this a bug, since it is perfectly legitimate for a style that implements the rules of a particular guide to work as expected only with its default settings, but you can ping the author of `windycity` about it at https://github.com/brianchase/windycity/issues and ask for a new feature/support for the various `...date` options.