# Remove letters from biblatex windycity style reflist environment

Tags: biblatex, windycity

Related to [my other question:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550070/removing-empty-parentheses-around-month-in-biblatex-windycity-style-reflist-envi) I cite in my text using footnotes and have the bibliography sorted by date. I need the `reflist` option in `windycity` to ensure that the bibliography is sorted by date and has the date immediately following the author. When I cite works from the same author from the same year, letters are added behind the year in the bibliography. This makes sense for inline author-date citations, but not for notes citations. Can I prevent this from happening?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[reflist=true, style=windycity, date=year]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\begin{document}
    \cite{knuth:ct:c}
    
    \cite{knuth:ct:b}   
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suppress year label letter in biblatex author-year styles on a per-bibliography or per-keyword basis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63500/suppress-year-label-letter-in-biblatex-author-year-styles-on-a-per-bibliography)

Comment: I voted not to close the question as a duplicate since the other question specifically was about suppressing the `extradate` info per-bibliography in case there are multiple bibliographies in a document. If one wants to suppress the `extardate` info for all bibliographies (for example because there is only one), then there are other, simpler solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conceptually nicest way to get rid of the `extradate` field/the disambiguation letter after the year is to tell `biblatex` not to calculate the `labeldate` at all by passing the option `labeldateparts=false`.

But `windycity` assumes `labeldateparts=true` and does not work properly if the option is set to `false`.

So here is the next best workaround that suppresses the field `extradata` (and the companion field `extradatescope`) as they are read from the `.bbl` file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[reflist=true, style=windycity, date=year]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldInputHandler{extradate}{\def\NewValue{}}
\DeclareFieldInputHandler{extradatescope}{\def\NewValue{}}

\begin{document}
  \cite{knuth:ct:c}

  \cite{knuth:ct:b}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Knuth, Donald E. 1986. TeX: The Program. Vols. B of Computers & Typesetting. Reading, Mass. Addison-Wesley.]

Of course that means the `extradate` is really gone and `\parencite`s are no longer unique.

If you want the letters gone only in the bibliography, use

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{extradate}%
  \clearfield{extradatescope}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering to your edit:

You can modify the environment using the code form here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63865/29873

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[reflist=true, style=windycity, date=year]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\defbibenvironment{nodis}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\clearfield{extradate}\item}

\begin{document}
    \cite{knuth:ct:c}
    
    \cite{knuth:ct:b}   
    \printbibliography
    \printbibliography[env=nodis]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

From the manual:

> **reflist**
>
> Use this option to print a bibliography in the author-date format, what CMOS calls a reference list.

If you don't want that format, don't use that option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=windycity, date=year]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\begin{document}
    \cite{knuth:ct:c}
    
    \cite{knuth:ct:b}   
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I need the bibliography to be sorted by date. I need reflist is the way to achieve that. I have rephrased the question to make that more clear.